# How to deploy a database programmatically from an Asp.Net application using an existing database/schema as a template?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, database, .net-4.0, multi-tenant

**Question:**

I am creating an Asp.Net application that has a multi-tenant data architecture with separate databases for each tenant.  I need to be able to create and deploy databases programmatically from the application when a new tenant signs up. What is the best way to maintain a template database/schema/script and use it to deploy a new database on the server.

**Note:**

I am using .Net 4.0 for the application and SQL Server 2008 R2 for the server.

**Current Workaround:**

Currently a default template database is maintained on the server. Changes to the database are done through Visual Studio to maintain versioning through source control. When a new database needs to be deployed:

1. Create a new database on the server using [Database.Create](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms205243.aspx).
2. Then use [Transfer.TransferData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.transfer.transferdata.aspx) to transfer just the schema over to the new database. Or, use [Transfer.ScriptTransfer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.transfer.scripttransfer.aspx) and store the script in memory for subsequent deployments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your deployment should be based on scripts that create the database from scratch. Any schema modification you make, make it through a script that upgrades the database schema. See [Version Control and Your Database](http://rusanu.com/2009/05/15/version-control-and-your-database/) for a more extended discussion of the topic.

The alternative of doing diff tools based deployment put you at the mercy of the tools decision on how to handle the diff (with large tables, this can get very dangerous if the tool decided to to a copy-based modification) and also puts you at the mercy of whatever support the diff tool has for automation, which makes the failure/retry handling, how should I put it,... 'fun'.

Comment: This is a great article on version control. I am currently doing this in visual studio using a database project. However, the issue that I am faced with is deploying the database programmatically from an Asp.Net application. In your article you mention using VSDBCMD, but that requires the application to be fully trusted and the Asp.Net application is only partially trusted. I have also tried using SMO, but I could not find a method to deploy from the generated schema file. If I am missing something please let me know. Thanks

Comment: I used raw .SQL files, hand written, quite successfully, to manage upgrades from v. N to v. N+1, as described at the beginning of the article. It requires to understand how to write the .SQL for *each* schema changes. I even wrote a library to handle execution of .SQL files (with `GO`) inside the application: http://code.google.com/p/dbutilsqlcmd/

Comment: Handwriting all of the changes to the database from the begining might get a little messy. We many implement something like this closer to release when the versioning is more important. For now we are looking for a little more automated process. I cited our current workaround above. What do you think?

Comment: Your current workaround will work for small databases. As soon as your tenants approach serious DB sizes (hundreds of GB) the transfer of data into a new database will prove prohibitive. Since I don't know you business model it may well be that a +100GB tenant is never going to be a problem.